# insert dropdown List data only ID to table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have 2 tables: tbleducation, and tblemployee. The tblemployee table has fields such as: employeeID, employeeName, etc. And tbleducation has fields such as: Id, employeeID, etc.

I want to create a dropwdownlist that selects an employeeID given an employeeName from the tblemployee table so that it can be inserted into tbleducation. I have written the code as follows:

**model**

```
public class UserModels
{

    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employee { set; get; }
}
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Education(FormCollection edu)
{
    tblEmployee_Education education = new tblEmployee_Education();
    education.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(edu["EmployeeName"].ToString());
    education.Duration = edu["Duration"].ToString();
    education.Certificate = edu["Certificate"].ToString();
    education.Country = edu["Country"].ToString();
    education.SchoolName = edu["SchoolName"].ToString();
    education.Major = edu["Major"].ToString();
    education.SubDescript = edu["SubDescript"].ToString();
    context.AddTotblEmployee_Education(education);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmployeeName, Model.Employee, "select EmployeeName")%>
```

---

When I tried to insert I got the following error message:

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint FK_tblEmployee_Education_tblEmployee_Employee". The conflict occurred in database "MP_DBS_old", table "dbo.tblEmployee_Employee", column 'Code'. The statement has been terminated."

I know that this error occurred because the value from dropdownlist is a string and the database needs an integer (employeeID). I really do not know how to fix it. Anyone help me please!

Comment: Are you sure thats why you get the error.  It seems its a conflict with foreign key constraints.  Do you have a row in the table using a specific key that you are trying to insert into that table again?

Comment: I'm sure with the error message and the reason that make it error like this as I told you it is only my thinking.Anyway, I do not understand what the "specific key "mean in your question that you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are trying to insert EmployeeName instead of EmployeeID.

Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmployeeName, Model.Employee, "select EmployeeName")%>: error

You are populating EmployeeName int dropdowmlist . Correct line would be this

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmployeeID , Model.Employee, "select EmployeeName")%>
```

Next you have to make correction in this line:

```
    education.EmployeeID =  Convert.ToInt32(edu["EmployeeID "].ToString())
```

I think this will solbe your problem

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer but I got an error in the point `education.EmployeeID = edu["EmployeeID "];` and show the message"can not implicitly convert type string to integer".Data type of EmployeeID in database is integer.please help me,

Comment: check edu["EmployeeID "] is not null then Convert it in into interger

Comment: Thanks,But when I convert it to integer: ' education.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(edu["EmployeeID"].ToString());'. It will show the error like this:"Input string was not in a correct format".

Comment: That means your employeeID is null check the data.